# Apostol: How to calculate work by force field along intersection of sphere and cylinder.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, vectors, line-integrals

This question is about line integrals in cartesian and cylindrical coordinates.

It is based on the following problem from Apostol's *Calculus*, Volume II, chapter 10 "Line Integrals", section 10.9

> 6. Calculate the work done by the force field $$f(x,y,z)=y^2\hat{i}+z^2\hat{j}+x^2\hat{k}\tag{1}$$ along the curve of
>    intersection of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ and the cylinder
>    $$x^2+y^2=ax\tag{2}$$ where $$z\geq 0\tag{3}$$ and $$a>0\tag{4}$$ The path is traversed in a
>    direction that appears clockwise when viewed from high above the
>    $xy$-plane.

The answer from Apostol's book is $\pi a^3/4$.

**Initial Attempt**

At first I did everything in cartesian coordinates.

From (2) we have

$$y=\pm\sqrt{ax-x^2}\tag{5}$$

Subbing (2) into (1) and solving for $z$ we have

$$z=\sqrt{a^2-ax}\tag{6}$$

From (5) and (6) we have the condition $x\in [0,a]$.

If we let $x$ be our parameter, a parametrization of the intersection of the sphere and the cylinder is given by the two equations in (7) (notice the $\pm$ on the $\hat{j}$ component)

$$\vec{r}(t)=t\hat{i}\pm\sqrt{at-t^2}\hat{j}+\sqrt{a^2-at}\hat{k}\tag{7}, t\in [0,a]$$

Here is a plot of the two curves that give the full intersection (for $a=2$)

[image]

Hence

$$d\vec{r}=(\hat{i}\pm\frac{a-2t}{2\sqrt{at-t^2}}\hat{j}+\frac{-a}{2\sqrt{a^2-at}}\hat{k})dt\tag{8}$$

and

$$f(\vec{r}(t))=(at-t^2)\hat{i}+(a^2-at)\hat{j}+t^2\hat{k}\tag{9}$$

And the work done by the force field on this curve is

$$\int_C \vec{f}\cdot d\vec{r}=\int_0^a \vec{f}(\vec{r}(t))\cdot d\vec{r}(t)dt\tag{10}$$

$$=\int_0^a \left(at-t^2+\frac{(a^2-at)(a-2t)}{2\sqrt{at-t^2}}-\frac{at^2}{2\sqrt{a^2-at}}\right )dt \tag{11}$$

**My first question is if this approach is correct so far.** This integral does not seem easy, and using Maple to solve it doesn't yield an answer.

**Second Attempt**

Then I tried with cylindrical coordinates, a topic that still eludes me.

The sphere is

$$r^2+z^2=a^2\tag{12}$$

and the cylinder is

$$r^2=ar\cos{\theta} \implies r=a\cos{\theta}\tag{13}$$

From these two equations we obtain

$$z=\sqrt{a^2-r^2}=\sqrt{a^2-a^2\cos^2{\theta}}=a\sin{\theta}\tag{14}$$

So at this point we have a parametrization of the intersection.

$$r=a\cos{\theta}$$
$$\theta=\theta$$
$$z=a\sin{\theta}$$

And if we plot this, we get something that seems to make sense as well

[image]

except that we have to remember that our intersection has $z\geq 0$, so it our intersection is the top part of the plot above, and so coincides with the plot we obtained when we used cartesian coordinates.

**Now is the part that is more murky for me.**

We have

$$\vec{f}(\vec{r}(\theta))=a^2\cos^2{\theta}\sin^2{\theta}\hat{i}+a^2\sin^2{\theta}\hat{j}+a^2\cos^4{\theta}\hat{k}\tag{15}$$

$$\vec{r}(\theta)=r(\theta)\hat{r}(\theta)+z(\theta)\hat{k}\tag{16}$$

$$=a\cos{\theta}\hat{r}(\theta)+a\sin{\theta}\hat{k}\tag{17}$$

$$=a\cos^2{\theta}\hat{i}+a\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}\hat{j}+a\sin{\theta}\hat{k}\tag{18}$$

Then

$$\frac{d\vec{r}(\theta)}{d\theta}=-2a\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}\hat{i}+(-a\sin^2{\theta}+a^2\cos^2{\theta})\hat{j}+a\cos{\theta}\hat{k}\tag{18}$$

Thus, if this is correct, then the line integral is

$$\int_C \vec{f}\cdot d\vec{r}=\int_{\pi}^0\left ( -2a^3\sin^3{\theta}\cos^3{\theta}-a^3\sin^4{\theta}+a^4\sin^2{\theta}\cos^2{\theta}+a^3\cos^5{\theta} \right )d\theta\tag{19}$$

Note that I chose the integration limits by looking at the parameterized equations and figuring out the values of $\theta$ that trace out the trajectory we want.

For example, consider $a=2$, as in the plots above. If we start at $\theta=0$ which corresponds to $(r,\theta,z)=(2,0,0)$ and move to $\theta=\pi/2$ which is $(r,\theta,z)=(0,\pi/2,2)$. This is halfway. Then we go to $\theta=\pi$ which takes us back to the starting point, but now with coordinates $(-2,\pi,0)$. However, this is counterclockwise, and we want clockwise, as per the problem statement. Hence the limits go from $\pi$ to $0$.

Using Maple, (19) evaluates to

$$\frac{\pi a^3}{4}\tag{2}$$

So my questions are the following

- is the approach in Cartesian coordinates just destined to fail because that integral is too difficult to solve?
- is there some easier way than what I did above with the cylindrical coordinates?

**Final Note:** As sometimes happens, in the course of carefully writing out my question and making sure it is well organized and clear for the reader, I sometimes end up learning. And it seems that I did reach the correct result after all with the cylindrical coordinates.

However, my questions remain about if this was all way too cumbersome and if there is a smarter way.

Comment: Cylindrical coordinates is the way to go. The cylinder limits $\theta$ to being between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$. You are sloppy when you say $z=a\sin\theta$; why?

Comment: $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ is the sphere. Also, since $x=r\cos{\theta}$ and $y=r\sin{\theta}$ then $x^2+y^2=r^2$, which are simply the equations to convert from cartesian to cylindrical. If I sub in $x^2+y^2=r^2$ into the sphere equation I get $r^2+z^2=a^2$ and then $z=\sqrt{a^2-r^2}$. But I also have the cylinder equation, which gives $r=a\cos{\theta}$, so that $r^2=a^2-\cos^2{\theta}$. Hence, I have $z=\sqrt{a^2-r^2}=\sqrt{a^2-a^2\cos^2{\theta}}=a\sin{\theta}$.

Comment: Perhaps I was sloppy when I used the cylinder equation. It starts as $x^2+y^2=ax$, which becomes $r^2=ar\cos{\theta}$. I simply cancelled the $r$ on appearing on each side. But $r$ can also be negative. I feel like I lost information by cancelling. However, I can't see how $\theta$ is restricted to $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. As far as I can tell, any $\theta$ works, and a full ride around the circle of the cylinder is also from $0$ to $\pi$.

Comment: Think in the $xy$-plane. The circle is only in quadrants 1 and 4. And, except in precalculus classes, we always try to take $r\ge 0$. Next, you need to be careful to remember that $\sqrt{b^2} = |b|$.

Comment: The integral you got in Cartesian is not as nasty as it may seem. Substitutions like [(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) and [(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution) can be used for the integral with $\sqrt{at-t^2}$; the other with $\sqrt{a^2-at}$ can be tackled by replacing $a^2-at$.